# pandas python optimize profit, linear optimization

Tags: python, pandas

i have a df with tresholds and profits:

```
import numpy as np import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=6) 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,3),index=dates,columns=['Value1', 'Value2', 'Profit']) 
df['Profit'] = df['Profit']*100 


print(df.to_string())

total_profit = df['Profit'].loc[(df.Value1 > 0) & (df.Value2 >= 0)].sum()

print(total_profit)
```

is there a panda-way to optimize total_profit by finding the best fitting margings for the tresholds of filtering value1 and value2?

I mean i could loop over the DF and increase / decrease the filter-values until i find the best fitting value ... but i guess someone has already done this  ... maybe sci-py?

so i basically need a function returning the best fits for value1 and value2, so i can filter my DF and optimize total_profit. the assumption is, that there is a correlation between value1, value2 and profit.

thanks and best wishes,
e.

Comment: Could you give an example input and the output you would like to get? I don't understand very well what you are trying to achieve... You want a couple of thresholds for `Value1` and `Value2` such that when you filter your data by those thresholds the sum of `Profit` is maximized?

Comment: @jdehesa so the example above is basically the in- and output. df is my input dataframe which has n values and a profit column. the problem here ist, that this is random data in my example. my real data have a correlation between the two values and the profit. So i'm looking for a way to find the best possible fit for my Value1 and Value2 filtering to maximize total_profit ... as you said. Thanks!!

Comment: Given that your 2 margins *and* your profit are completely random, I don't think there is an easier/smarter/faster way, as this is not in any way a smooth mathematical function. If your example is, in that sense, incorrect, and your real data does have a relationship with the two margins, we'd have to know that relation.

Comment: If you're just thinking of using a built-in Pandas method to brute-force find the solution to your problem, instead of manually coding a (double) for loop: I don't know of one, but `DataFrame.apply()` may be a first step to look at.

Comment: I know that its hart to tell because of the random values. but nevertheless should it be possible to find the best fit (i guess :)). i recall that i did something like that with excels linear optimization years back ... so i though that there might be something similar in python. i would have expected that i get at least 2 values (value1 and value2) which would subselect the df in one line where i have a positive profit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you only want to use observed values for df.Value1 and df.Value2, the following will work.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=6) 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,3),index=dates,columns=['Value1', 'Value2', 'Profit']) 
df['Profit'] = df['Profit']*100 

print(df.to_string())

# create list of all possible value pairs
vals = [[i,j] for i in df.Value1 for j in df.Value2]

# create list of profits from all possible value pairs
total_profit = [df['Profit'].loc[(df.Value1 > i) & (df.Value2 >= j)].sum() for i, j in vals]

# get index of maximum profit
max_index = total_profit.index(max(total_profit))

# get values that correspond to max profit
vals[max_index]

Out[9]: [-0.51914224014959032, -0.73918945103973344]
```